# Export multiple lines to Excel from a read file

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have some code that is currently being used to get a single line of data from an Excel spreadsheet and convert it to another spreadsheet to send to my clients. What I'm trying to do is to get this code to return multiple lines on the final spreadsheet. Right now I'm doing this:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathConn))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < excelSheets.Length; i++)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" +
        excelSheets[i] + "]", conn);
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(dt);
        tring dtBrokerName = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("ProducerName");                   

        //[Sets numerous fields]

        // create final output report based on imported data
        GenerateExcelData(dtBrokerName, dtExpirationDate, dtPolicyNumber, 
        dtCurrentPrice, tier, usage, city, dtcValue);
    }
}
```

I pass the information I want on the final report into this method:

```
public void GenerateExcelData(string dtBrokerName, DateTime dtExpirationDate, string dtPolicyNumber, 
                              double dtCurrentPrice, string tier, string usage, string city, decimal dtcValue)
{
    CreateExcelDoc BatchRenewalReport = new CreateExcelDoc();
    //creates the header row
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 1, "Producer", "A1", "A1", 0, "#", true, 30, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 2, "Expiration Date", "B1", "B1", 0, "#", true, 15, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 3, "Policy #", "C1", "C1", 0, "#", true, 12.86, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 4, "Current Price", "D1", "D1", 0, "#",  true, 15.71, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 5, "New Price", "E1", "E1", 0, "#", true, 15.71, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 6, "$ Difference", "F1", "F1", 0, "#", true, 12.14, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 7, "% Difference", "G1", "G1", 0, "#", true, 12.14, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 8, "Tier", "H1", "H1", 0, "#", true, 15, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 9, "Usage", "I1", "I1", 0, "#", true, 9, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 10, "City", "J1", "J1", 0, "#", true, 16.43, "n");
    BatchRenewalReport.createHeaders(1, 11, "DTC", "K1", "K1", 0, "#", true, 6.43, "n");

    //fills additional rows
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 1, dtBrokerName, "A2", "A2", "");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 2, dtExpirationDate.ToString(), "B2", "B2", "mm/dd/yyyy");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 3, dtPolicyNumber, "C2", "C2", "");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 4, dtCurrentPrice.ToString(), "D2", "D2", "$#,##0");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 5, "3117", "E2", "E2", "$#,##0");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 6, "=E2-D2", "F2", "F2", "$#,##0");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 7, "=(E2/D2)-1", "G2", "G2", "#.#0%");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 8, tier, "H2", "H2", "");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 9, usage, "I2", "I2", "");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 10, city, "J2", "J2", "");
    BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 11, dtcValue.ToString(), "K2", "K2", "0#.##0");
}
```

Which utilizes this class, which was developed by a 3rd party:

```
class CreateExcelDoc
{
    private Excel.Application app = null;
    private Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
    private Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
    private Excel.Range workSheet_range = null;

    public CreateExcelDoc()
    {
        createDoc();
    }

    public void createDoc()
    {
        try
        {
            app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
            worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public void createHeaders(int row, int col, string htext, string cell1,
    string cell2, int mergeColumns, string b, bool font, double size, string
    fcolor)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, col] = htext;
        workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
        workSheet_range.Merge(mergeColumns);

        switch (b)
        {
            case "Black":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "Gray":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = Color.Gray.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "Red":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = Color.Red.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "Green":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = Color.ForestGreen.ToArgb();
                break;
            case "Yellow":
                workSheet_range.Interior.Color = Color.LightYellow.ToArgb();
                break;
            default:
                //  workSheet_range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color..ToArgb();
                break;
        }

        workSheet_range.Borders.Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
        workSheet_range.Font.Bold = font;
        workSheet_range.ColumnWidth = size;

        if (fcolor.Equals(""))
        {
            workSheet_range.Font.Color = Color.White.ToArgb();
        }
        else
        {
            workSheet_range.Font.Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
        }
    }

    public void addData(int row, int col, string data,
        string cell1, string cell2, string format)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, col] = data;
        workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
        workSheet_range.Borders.Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
        workSheet_range.NumberFormat = format;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the program to read each row in the Excel file that I import and return the values row by row on the export report. My attempts to alter the:

```
BatchRenewalReport.addData(2, 1, dtBrokerName, "A2", "A2", "");
```

lines have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: In your place I'd drop that class and use EPPlus. A simple `sheet.LoadFromDataTable` or `LoadFromCollection` will create a table with the data and headers. You can then apply styles as needed, rename the headers etc. I think it even respects Data Annotation attributes so you could set the `DisplayName` attribute for each column or class property

Comment: EPPLus is definitely not a bad Option, I am using it in many applications and it works great

Comment: That's kinda the feeling I was getting. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll convert it over to EPPlus.

Comment: Actually it seems like EPPlus unfortunately won't work, since I need to be able to read both .xls & xlsx files.